# Android PlusOneButton

Tags: android, google-plus-one

I'm trying to make plusone button works inside my android app.

I did this:

```
m_plusClient = new PlusClient(this, this, this);
```

Then:

```
m_plusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) m_view.findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
m_plusOneButton.initialize(((SinglePlace)getActivity()).m_plusClient, url, 0);
```

Button is there, but if I click it, it shows an indefinite progress bar and does nothing. No callbacks are called on plus client...

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps first:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started
before you jump to +1 button section.